# Add 4 to each digit and multiply

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math

This question appeared in my younger brother's tenth-year math contest, and he couldn't solve it:

> The number $120$ has the property that, after each of its digits is increased by $4$, the product of the resulting digits equals the original number (i.e., $(1+4)(2+4)(0+4)=5\cdot6\cdot4=120$). Find the only other three-digit number with this property.

The answer is

> $(3+4)(1+4)(5+4)=7\cdot5\cdot9=\boxed{315}$

Clearly we have to check a bunch of numbers; we can narrow it down by considering only composite numbers (presumably those with lots of factors), and by bounding (not all three digits can be high, e.g., $999\ll13\cdot13\cdot13$). But even then, I couldn't figure out how to limit the number of possibilities enough so that I could finish checking them manually in a reasonable time (this was in a timed contest).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Permutation of digits is irrelevant, so at least you dont have to go through all numbers, only through digits combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Partial answer:**

We want to find the number $n$ whit decimal expansion $abc$ which
$$10^2a+10b+c=(a+4)(b+4)(c+4)$$
Then the following must hold true:
$$c=abc \mod 2$$
$$2b+c=abc \mod 4$$
If $c$ is odd, $a,b$ must be also odd. Then:
$$c+2=abc \mod 4$$
and
$$3=ab \mod 4$$
Then one must be $1$ and the other $3$ in modulus $4$. It is,

$(13c)$ or $(31c)$

$(17c)$ or $(71c)$

$(53c)$ or $(35c)$

$(57c)$ or $(75c)$

$(93c)$ or $(39c)$

$(97c)$ or $(79c)$

Then, we only need to test it for every $c$ odd number, i.e. 30 cases in total, although we could discard some numbers in advance (759,757,977,..).

Comment: You can easily rule out $c\equiv1$ mod $5$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $a, b, c$ be the three digits of the number

I think one of the elementary way is to first fix $a$ and then determine the range for the product $(b+4)(c+4)$.

For example, when $a=3, a+4=7\Rightarrow 40<(b+4)(c+4)<60$

Now, check which combination suits for $(b+4)$ and $(c+4)$, $(5,9),(6,7),(6,8),(6,9),(7,8)$

Comment: @JohnChessant  my pleasure  :)